# where can I find the stellar serialization format?

Tags: transactions

I'm trying to understand the implementation of Steller in TrustWallet core. There are a number of fields added to a signed message [in this changeset](https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core/pull/1247/commits/6de2f2bf52ea35815797b46745cc1035c77964ca). Where is the documentation that describes the format of this data?

Answer (score 0):

What is encoded in the change set is the XDR of assets and operations, you can find the details here:
https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/blob/master/xdr/curr/Stellar-transaction.x
https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/blob/master/xdr/curr/Stellar-ledger-entries.x

For a higher level, you can find the operation list here:
https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations